# How to go up and down in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I actually have this piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i, row;
    
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){
        row =3-i%3;
        printf("%d ",row);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1
```

but I would like that it is

```
3 2 1 1 2 3 3 2 1
```

this means "inverting" the counter at each 3 elements but I cannot figure out how to do this...

Comment: Perhaps use multiple loops? Don't overcomplicate things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modulo to toggle `increment` from 1 to -1.
If 9 is change to 18 or 24 the pattern will continue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void) {
    int row = 3;
    int increment = -1;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf ( "%d ",row + (1 == increment));
        row += increment;
        if ( 0 == row % 3) {
            increment *= -1;
        }
    }
    printf ( "\n");
    return 0;
}
```

With 24 the output

```
3 2 1 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You may recognize whether you're in an odd or in an even triple and calculate the `row` value accordingly:

```
int i, row;

for (i = 0; i < 9; ++ i)
{
    if (i % 6 < 3)       // the first triple in a six ?
        row = 3 - i % 3;
    else                 // the second triple in a six
        row = 1 + i % 3;
    printf("%d ", row);
}
```

See it [working at godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2B9YzmTVbrgr3YLpkTvcmMzaY7GyiIq7nLVc3dNOC8Q2WsSnBZXs/XAsRVVQIK2scn0MOLfnw4LbW9Y1HXcrZ3nMAQRrQPd2%2BbrXVJBqxpOj5A5ZPJUNJfUJhqNMK3BZx5ARpHJ%2BoMDiAsX7IcjdRjOLrdYKWLIjIqKcFiqIqNI3BHk%2Bp7SPI/wyKQj4noMcCwDAiAoKgyx4OwZAUBAMKBHhDTIMAnCUXweEEH4/wQN4sGkN4bh5AAntI96kDCtimAQRy0KwHEnqQWAauo7BMfgxCZIYZz/CJCyZNYtFMaqZRMaweDeMQ7GWFgTEEP2ticbufCqMAQgAGp4JgGxHIEpimXwdCMCwkk8C5ggiBITFKFiKhqJo2gqNp/yQIM3KIvBpTlOEJhmK0xSkE4tTJKkMQhGEdBJZlcThGl9T%2BO0ZSydknS5SVcV0FU%2BSFb0xVNNUlVNXV3TpQ0nCDJeIxjFwe4HjBIlnlI4iosiRLItw0zAMgyDNpwkIthAuCECQt4lNMli4fht5Yjq5gPrBL6kAgmDMFg/jaqQb7gZCgroliMjIji6J%2BrqMi6pwyKQVI0GkCZ6JIcecikCNCEgEhKHPqQ6FYcMvwqeQlDEaR/gBZg%2BBEI1/BuWwHCebjwhiJIIkbLpgSmQNUiHqQINwVIRwqYEKnTKgCZjRNU0zXNC1LU620kbtAqAf0R2oYMZ0XQ0137n98iA8DTHg7okPIcdr7vqiS2cDIgoyDInBA36U2Csigq/YKQ2gyr0NmXDDtIKj%2BHI0ROFC2RFFUVQNF0ZQjEiSxtDsc5PF8QJQlSZg4nAJJInSWV8lMUpyAqeMoPqXLoNaTpekYOMXFGXgJlSPegwXMwlk2XZDlOaX8i40w%2BNcLwRM%2BaToNKCUqjqCAWgaDoOfhddUXhApCGlVkxgQE4LWpe1RV5dlERWEUS8VPVGVVWVNUVavbSxTvlSdJvnWtQU%2B/JUCbVJIvXVDL1BPU7T9Ng9InOTdNs3zZR/MrVj60RabUFmjDaB1xbPkludS6lBNb63utwZEnAzZm04H6VEfpkG/X%2BorL86JALInNneZE6JUQfl4K/FWiF1aoVhphCASAEYswIK7Z2Z9MZrRxq5JuHlW6uWJr5MmFMqa/RfsraQTNEZqnZtMD%2B3Nv582WiA4WQouoQN3FA6WV1qY4ICJ%2BQUiCAJmzRAYv8AVKExWoXbE6b5sSQhxJRMhlEppYl1OiS21sGbqJOnLLEni35SG8YMMEoRjDcCAA).

For a condition `if (i % 6 < 3)` you may use a more explicit, but also a bit more complicated condition:

```
((i / 3) % 2 == 0)
```

– calculate the current triple's number first: `i / 3`, and then check if it's odd or even.

Answer (score 2):

Try `switch` :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int row = 3;
    int direction = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%d ", row);
        switch (i) {
            default: break;
            case 2: case 5: direction = 0; break;
            case 3: direction = 1; break;
            case 6: direction = -1; break;
        }
        row += direction;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i, row,incre=0,change=0;
    
    for(i=0; i<18; i++){
        if(change==0)
        {
            incre++;
            row =3-i%3;
            printf("%d ",row);
            if(incre>=3){
                change=1;
                incre=0;
                //printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else{
            incre++;
            row =1+i%3;
            printf("%d ",row);
            if(incre>=3){
                change=0;
                incre=0;
                //printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```